# Is there any way, I can get to the brief history of any words or phrases?

Tags: vocabulary, linguistics, morphology, derivational-morphology, inflectional-morphology

It's hard to remember the word until I get to the history or until I feel the word.

I'm wondering any apps or sites to help me out with this.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/, https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: To get the history of "glop", go on Google and type `etymology glop`.